# Don't understand behavior of Tasks in C#

Tags: c#, task, task-parallel-library

I'm hoping someone can help me understand what seems like some straightforward code. Clearly, I'm missing something. There are 2 things I don't understand about the behavior of this code:

1. If I let the code run, the last `Debug.WriteLine` for 'End Delay' never gets written. Why is this?
2. If I put a breakpoint on the `Task.WaitAll()` line in Main(), I see that `delayTask` has a status of `WaitingToRun` and the 'Begin Delay' `Debug.WriteLine` in `DoDelay()` doesn't happen, no matter how long I wait.  However, as soon as I F10 over the Task.WaitAll() line, I see 'Begin Delay' show up in output. Why does a breakpoint on the `Task.WaitAll()` line seem to prevent even **beginning** the task? This behavior doesn't change whether I use `Task.WaitAll(delayTask)` or `await delayTask`.

I'm running on .NET Framework 4.6.2, unfortunately, I don't have a choice about this.

Thanks to everyone who has posted.  I have an answer for the 1st question above - I changed 'async void DoDelay()' to 'async Task DoDelay()'. But I still don't have any explanation for the behavior in my 2nd question.

Update: As JonasH pointed out to me, all tasks stop when in break mode in VS.

For anyone who is interested, this article helped a lot with understanding what's going on: https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/understand-control-flow-async-await

```cs
static void Main(string[] args) 
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"Main-A: {DateTime.Now:mm:ss.fff}");
    Task delayTask = Task.Run(() => DoDelay(10000));
    Debug.WriteLine($"Main-B: {DateTime.Now:mm:ss.fff}");
    Task.WaitAll(delayTask);
}

static async void DoDelay(int delayMs) 
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"Begin Delay: {DateTime.Now:mm:ss.fff}");
    await Task.Delay(delayMs);
    Debug.WriteLine($"End Delay: {DateTime.Now:mm:ss.fff}");
}
```

Comment: By the way: you're not awaiting `DoDelay` in the anonymous method you're passing to `Task.Run`. It's fire and forget effectively.

Comment: Avoid `async void` whenever possible, as you cannot await it (it is in practoce used only for event handlers). Replace it by `async Task`.

Comment: Also: Go Async "all the way": make it `static async Task Main`. - Oh wait. Didn't see the Framework 4.6.2 ... not sure if it's possible there.

Comment: [Avoid async void](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void), unless it's an event handler. The `DoDelay` does not look like an event handler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Task delayTask = Task.Run(() => DoDelay(10000));

This will call the method `DoDelay(10000)` on a background thread, and return a task that completes when the method returns. However, `DoDelay` will return at the first `await` statement. The rest of the method will be run at some later time, but there is nothing that will wait for this to occur.

To fix this you should make your method return a Task, i.e. `async Task DoDelay(int delayMs)`. This will not affect when the method returns, but the returned task lets you wait for the entire method to complete. This can be made more simple by using a async main method:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args) {
    Debug.WriteLine($"Main-A: {DateTime.Now:mm:ss.fff}");
    var delayTask = DoDelay(10000);
    Debug.WriteLine($"Main-B: {DateTime.Now:mm:ss.fff}");
    await delayTask;
    Debug.WriteLine($"Main-C: {DateTime.Now:mm:ss.fff}");
}

static async Task DoDelay(int delayMs) {
    Debug.WriteLine($"Begin Delay: {DateTime.Now:mm:ss.fff}");
    await Task.Delay(delayMs);
    Debug.WriteLine($"End Delay: {DateTime.Now:mm:ss.fff}");
}
```

Only use `async void` when you absolutely have to, i.e. event handlers in an UI, and then make sure you are handling failures of any awaited tasks. In the vast majority of cases, use `async Task` or `async Task<T>`

Comment: I'm not sure this is right. Async/await use idle time on the same thread, not necessarily a background thread.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I guess it depends how you interpret 'background thread', perhaps  'arbitrary threadpool thread' would be more accurate?

Comment: That's not really right, either. By default, async/await still do things in the **same thread**, just re-arranged to use idle time while certain things would otherwise block.

Comment: For clarity: in this case Task.Run() means he definitely _will_ have a separate thread, but that's not necessarily the case for all Tasks or async methods.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I was describing the behavior of the code that uses `Task.Run`, and that does not even use any async or await. And to be technical, await will continue the execution on the same 'context', i.e. either the UI thread, or a threadpool thread. Your comment about continuing on the same thread only applies in a UI context, not a console program.

Comment: @JonasH thank you for your comments.  I changed the code as you suggested, and when the code runs, I now see 'End Delay' also written to output.  About the second question I asked though, I still see the same behavior if I put a breakpoint on the await delayTask statement.  In other words the DoDelay() method doesn't seem to even begin until I F10 past the await statement.   Could you help me understand why?

Comment: @scantrell What do you mean by "no matter how long I wait"? No code will run while you are in "break mode", so waiting in this mode will not do anything. There is very little code between starting the and the wait, so the simplest explanation is that the scheduler have not gotten around to starting the task yet. Try adding a `Thread.Sleep` before the statement and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: @JonasH I mistakenly assumed that only the foreground code stopped in break mode.  Thanks for pointing out that all tasks stop in break mode.

Answer (score -2):

some Note: avoid using **async void** because you have to **await** on it to get result, So I change it to async Task

You have to use **delayTask.Wait();** for waiting to complete the task.

**Warning**: `delayTask.Wait()` is bad practice use `await delayTask;` instead.

use this instead of your code I do some changes on it:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {

  Debug.WriteLine($"Main-A: {DateTime.Now:mm:ss.fff}");
  Task delayTask = Task.Run(async () => await DoDelay(10000));
  Debug.WriteLine($"Main-B: {DateTime.Now:mm:ss.fff}");
  delayTask.Wait();
}

static async Task DoDelay(int delayMs)
{
  Debug.WriteLine($"Begin Delay: {DateTime.Now:mm:ss.fff}");
  await Task.Delay(delayMs);
  Debug.WriteLine($"End Delay: {DateTime.Now:mm:ss.fff}");
}
```

you can also use

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
```

and remove `Task.Run(async () => await DoDelay(10000));` and use `await DoDelay(10000)` and `await delayTask;` but it may not work it .NET framework 4.6.2

Comment: `await delayTask` not `delayTask.Wait`

Comment: `delayTask.Wait();` means dead end.

Comment: yes you are correct but we are in .NET framework 4.6.2 maybe we cannot use `static async Task Main(string[] args)`

Answer (score -3):

The correct implementation of the `async/await` pattern in this case is as the code below

```
static class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Main-A: {DateTime.Now:mm:ss.fff}");
        Task delayTask = Task.Run(async () => { await DoDelay(10000); });
        Task delayTaskSync = Task.Run(() => { DoDelaySync(10000); });
        Console.WriteLine($"Main-B: {DateTime.Now:mm:ss.fff}");
        Task.WaitAll(delayTask, delayTaskSync);
    }

    static async Task DoDelay(int delayMs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Begin Delay: {DateTime.Now:mm:ss.fff}");
        await Task.Delay(delayMs);
        Console.WriteLine($"End Delay: {DateTime.Now:mm:ss.fff}");
    }

    static void DoDelaySync(int delayMs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Begin Delay: {DateTime.Now:mm:ss.fff}");
        Task.Delay(delayMs).Wait();
        Console.WriteLine($"End Delay: {DateTime.Now:mm:ss.fff}");
    }
}
```

Here you can see an implementation with both an async function and a sync function.
The `Task.Run()` run a parallel task and inside that task you can use more task with `async/await` or use synchronous function.